# Better Way to Handle Dates in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, date

I was wondering which type of query is better to use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE >= '2010-7-20' AND DATE <= '2010-7-24'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_SUB('2010-07-24',INTERVAL 4 DAY) <= DATE
```

Comment: Excellent point guys, the second query does produce different results.  I also wish I could choose two correct answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I always use the `>=` and `<` combination.

So if you want to serch for a those four days you would use

```
where DATE >= '2010-07-20' AND DATE < '2010-07-24'
```

This ensures that you only get dates your interesrted in even if there's a mixtrure of acutal dates(with no time component ) and datetimes.

So if you had a date stored as  2010-07-20 09:00:00 and a date stored as 2010-07-20 they would both be included, but the date 2010-07-24 wouln't.

**I don't trust Between!**
I'm not sure about MySQL but BETWEEN in SQL Server would give you inclusive results so a row with a date of 2010-07-24 would be included when I wouldn't expect it to be if you wanted the four date period from the 20th? (20th, 21st, 22nd & 23rd)

So ANY date on the 24th shouldn't be included even if it was midnight..!

**Also...** 
Typically using functions in your criteria can prevent the optimizer using any indexes..!  Something to be aware of.

**More Importantly...**
The second query doesn't produce the same results as the first query...Is it all there?

Comment: BETWEEN is ANSI standard, and is inclusive on every database I've ever encountered - Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, SQLite...  And being inclusive is exactly what the OP's first query is - but the issue is that implicit date conversion will turn '2010-07-24' into July 24th, 2010 at 00:00:00 in the morning - it'll only return dates that are at exactly that time, not for the entire day of July 24th/etc.  Your fear is irrational

Comment: "Your fear is irrational", I have no doubt that's true :o)

Comment: So quick question. What if you wanna use NOW() but you have to default the time to 00:00:00 and 23:59:59? As I am using `date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND date<= NOW()` It is taking the current time as well when I need it to take mindight of yesterday and 1 second before midnight today

Comment: and I do realise this is a 13 year old question

Answer (score 4):

use between?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2010-7-20' AND '2010-7-24'`

Comment: That's no different than the first query, BETWEEN is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on data and business rules, the two queries will produce different results.

The first query, which can be re-written to use BETWEEN (for legibility, no performance change), is guaranteed to return rows whose `date` column value is between July 20th at 00:00:00  and July 24th at 00:00:00.

The second query will return records whose `date` column value is greater or equal to July 20th, 00:00:00.  If there are dates in the future, this query will return those as well.  Because a default constraint will only set the `date` column if no value is provided - you need a check constraint (not supported by MySQL on any engine though syntax exists) or trigger to ensure that data matches your business rules.

### Conclusion

Being explicit is best - easier to understand, which makes it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples don't produce the same result!

The first one would be better with BETWEEN - it searches between two dates

The second one just searches for entries with DATE => 2010-07-20

These are totally differen operations!